# How to read a filename in the value field of a RESX file

Tags: c#, resx

The issue I am stuck with is how to iterate through a resource file when a file name is the value. I first tried to use DictionaryEntry and found the same issue as well. Would you be able to provide some guidance on how to resolve this problem?

### Prereqs:

**A local resource file with the following string resource value:**

```
Name                 |Value                                   |Comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MouseImageUrl2.Text  |protected/images/tutorial/goodwork.gif  |protected/images/tutorial/goodwork.gif
```

- **Persistence**: Embedded in .resx
- **Type**: System.String, mscorlib,
  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

**The following operation (using System.Windows.Forms;):**

```
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\Projects\Working\TFS\Source\Help.aspx.resx");
IEnumerator enumerator = rsxr.GetEnumerator();
```

### Details:

This is the error that I receive (The solution is located at C:\Projects\Team - SE\Code_PSGDashboard\Development\TAS_LanguageProcessor\TAS_LanguageProcessor):

```
ResX file Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Projects\Team - SE\Code_PSGDashboard\Development\TAS_LanguageProcessor\TAS_LanguageProcessor\bin\Protected\Images\tutorial\goodwork.gif'. Line 123, position 5. cannot be parsed.
```

I am using DictionaryEntry, but the provided code does produce the same results. The DictionaryEntry routine that will throw the same error is:

```
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\Projects\Working\TFS\Source\Help.aspx.resx");
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Resources;

/// <summary>   Resource item. </summary>
public static class ResourceItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This routine is responsible for getting all the comments from the original files and then
    /// adding them to the new resource files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputResX">    The path to the source resx. </param>
    /// <param name="outputResX">   The path to the destination resx. </param>
    /// <returns>   True if changes were made. </returns>
    public static bool CopyComments(string inputResX, string outputResX)
    {
        bool changesMade = false;

        // Populate a Hashtable containing the DataNodes in the output file
        var output = new Hashtable();
        using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(outputResX))
        {
            reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
            IEnumerator enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var entry = (DictionaryEntry)enumerator.Current;

                var dataNode = (ResXDataNode)entry.Value;
                output.Add(dataNode.Name, dataNode);
            }
        }

        // Search the Hashtable for equivalent DataNodes in the input file
        using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(inputResX))
        {
            reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
            IEnumerator enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var entry = (DictionaryEntry)enumerator.Current;

                var inputDataNode = (ResXDataNode)entry.Value;

                if (output.ContainsKey(inputDataNode.Name))
                {
                    var outputDataNode = (ResXDataNode)output[inputDataNode.Name];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDataNode.Comment) && outputDataNode.Comment != inputDataNode.Comment)
                    {
                        // Update the output resx’s comments with the input resx’s comments
                        outputDataNode.Comment = inputDataNode.Comment;
                        changesMade = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (changesMade)
        {
            // Write the changes back to the output file
            using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(outputResX))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in output)
                {
                    writer.AddResource(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value);
                }

                writer.Generate();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

        return changesMade;
    }
}
```

This allowed me to write new resource files and copy the comments to the new one and save it.